# How does Dodelson calculate the number density of a particle species?

Tags: nucleosynthesis

In chapter three of **Modern Cosmology**, *Dodelson* models the evolution of a particle plasma as the universe expands.  On page 61, the author gives the formula for the species-dependent equilibrium density as:$$n_i=g_i\space e^{\mu_i/T}\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}e^{-E_1/T}\tag1$$For equilibrium (when a species is created as often as it's annihilated), we have:$$n_i^{(0)}=g_i\space\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}e^{-E_1/T}\tag2$$Now this is the part I don't follow.  How does Dodelson go from Eq. (2) to this:$$n_i^{(0)}=g_i\left(\frac{m_iT}{2\pi}\right)^{3/2} e^{-m_1/T}\tag3$$I get that $\int d^3 p=\frac{p^3}{({2\pi})^3\space6}$, and I get that $E_1=m_1$, and I get that $p=\sqrt{E^2-m^2}$, but I can't put them together.  How do we go from Eq. (2) to Eq. (3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid your primary error is one of elementary calculus.  $\int d^3p$ is not equal to $\frac{p^3}{(2\pi)^3 6}$.  Secondly, $E\neq m$ (how could it, since as you correctly say in your next words, $p=\sqrt{E^2-m^2}$??).

To evaluate this integral we go to spherical coordinates, in which $\int d^3 p = \int_0^\infty p^2 dp \int_{0}^{\pi} sin(\theta)\space d\theta \int _0^{2\pi} d\phi = 4\pi \int_0^\infty p^2 dp$, where we've used the spherical symmetry of the problem to evaluate the angular integrals.  From there, we have

$$n_i^{(0)} = g_i \frac{4\pi}{(2\pi)^3} \int_0^\infty p^2 e^{-\sqrt{p^2+m_i^2}/T} dp$$
This integral doesn't have a nice form.  However, if we assume that $m_i \gg p$, we can approximate $\sqrt{p^2+m_i^2} \approx m_i + \frac{p^2}{2m_i}$ (a non-relativistic approximation), which allows us to simplify to

$$n_i^{(0)} \approx g_i \frac{4\pi}{(2\pi)^3}e^{-m_i/T} \int_0^\infty p^2 e^{-p^2/2m_iT} dp$$
$$ = g_i\frac{4\pi}{(2\pi)^3} e^{-m_i/T} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}(2m_iT)^{3/2}$$
which simplifies after a bit of algebra to
$$n_i^{(0)} \approx g_i e^{-m_i/T} \left(\frac{m_iT}{2\pi}\right)^{3/2}$$

The non-relativistic approximation is valid as long as $m\gg T$ or, in SI units, $m\gg \frac{k_B T}{c^2}$.

Comment: I don't understand the terminology of $\int_{-1}^1 d(\cos(\theta))$. Is this supposed to be $\int_{-1}^{1} \cos(\theta) d\theta$?  Obviously it's supposed to result in $2\pi$, but I don't see this step completely because the notation is unfamiliar.

Comment: @GluonSoup It’s a fairly common notation which is useful when only cosine (or no angular dependence at all) shows up in the integrand. In this case we have the latter, so $\int_{-1}^1 d(\cos(\theta)) = \int_0^\pi \sin(\theta)d\theta = 2$.

Comment: Following your assumption that $m_i\gg p$, I would like to understand how I compare momentum to mass.  If, say, the mass of a proton, $m_P$, was $1.67\times 10^{-27}\space kg$, then to what, exactly, am I comparing this?

Comment: @GluonSoup Everything here is taking place in natural units, where the Boltzmann constant $k_B$ and the speed of light $c$ are set to 1.  If you want to use SI units, then the assumption would be that $m_i \gg p/c$.  In different terms, the particle's kinetic energy is much less than its mass energy, or its velocity is much less than $c$.  All of these approximations are equivalent.

Comment: So then, we're assuming that the motion of particles in this 1 MeV soup is non-relativistic?  That' they're basically at rest compared to $c$?

Comment: @GluonSoup Yes.  1 MeV is highly non-relativistic for protons, since $m_P c^2 \approx 1$ GeV.  It is, however, highly *relativistic* for electrons, sincd $m_e c^2 \approx 0.5$ MeV.

Comment: I've been over this several times in MMa and I even cross referenced Wiki on the spherical coordinates.  This is what MMa gives for an integral of the above formula:$$\int d^3 p = \int_0^\infty p^2 dp \int_{0}^{\pi} sin(\theta)\space d\theta \int _0^{2\pi} d\phi = 4\pi^2 \int_0^\infty p^2 dp$$That is, the $\pi$ term is squared.  Was this a misprint on your side or is this really what you get when you take the integral?

Comment: @GluonSoup It’s really what you get. The theta integral gives you $2$, not $2\pi$.

Comment: I agree that that $\int_{0}^{\pi} sin(\theta)\space d\theta$ is 2, but I'm getting $2\pi^2$ for $\int _0^{2\pi} d\phi$

Comment: @GluonSoup I can't imagine how, that's just $\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi = \phi\big|^{2\pi}_0 = 2\pi-0 = 2\pi$.

Comment: Thank you.  That was it.  Mistake in the transcription.